# Not able to pass array into method

Tags: java, arrays

Why can't I send the appleArray, blueberryArray, and peanutArray to the calcTotalPies method?

```
 final int MAX_PIES = 81;
 final int MAX_PER_TYPE = 27;

 String typeOfPie = getPieType();
 while (!typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
     if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("apple")) {
         String[] appleArray = fillApple(typeOfPie, MAX_PER_TYPE);
     }
     else if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("blueberry")) {
         String[] blueberryArray = fillBlueberry(typeOfPie, MAX_PER_TYPE);
     }
     else if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("peanut")) {
         String[] peanutArray = fillPeanut(typeOfPie, MAX_PER_TYPE);
     }
     typeOfPie = getPieType();
}

if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
      int totalPies = calcTotalPies(appleArray, blueberryArray, peanutArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your code execution reaches to your method, if else block scopes inside while loop within which your arrays are declared have ended and they are not reachable. So you need to initialize them outside the loop.

Try this

```
final int MAX_PIES = 81;
final int MAX_PER_TYPE = 27;

String[] peanutArray = null;
String[] blueberryArray = null;
String[] appleArray = null;

String typeOfPie = getPieType();
while (!typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
    if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("apple")) {
        appleArray = fillApple(typeOfPie, MAX_PER_TYPE);
    } else if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("blueberry")) {
        blueberryArray = fillBlueberry(typeOfPie, MAX_PER_TYPE);
    } else if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("peanut")) {
        peanutArray = fillPeanut(typeOfPie, MAX_PER_TYPE);
    }
    typeOfPie = getPieType();
}

if (typeOfPie.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
    int totalPies = calcTotalPies(appleArray, blueberryArray, peanutArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A local variable is always declared within a block and only alive in this block (note: a method body or the body of an `if` or a loop is also a block).

You declared `appleArray`, `blueberryArray` and `peanutArray` only in their surrounding `if`-blocks, therefore they are not alive in the lowest `if`-block. The compiler should tell you something of these arrays not being defined.

Comment: Just to add a comment @dan: languages like Java and C have a notion called *"block scope*".  Code blocks are delimited by the curly braces.  Block scope assures that variables declared inside the block won't pollute the namespaces of other code domains in which they occur.  This enables modules in your project to remain decoupled from one another.